# Unable to format months with as.Date

Tags: r, date

I'm missing something obvious with the "format" section of as.Date. Consider this example

`d1 <- data.frame(d = c("1/Jan/1947", 
                       "1/Feb/1947",
                       "1/Mar/1947"),
                 d2 = c("Jan/1947", 
                       "Feb/1947",
                       "Mar/1947"))`

```
d1$date1 <- as.Date(x=d1$d, format="%d/%b/%Y")
d1$date2 <- as.Date(x=d1$d2, format="%b/%Y")

           d       d2      date1 date2
1 1/Jan/1947 Jan/1947 1947-01-01  <NA>
2 1/Feb/1947 Feb/1947 1947-02-01  <NA>
3 1/Mar/1947 Mar/1947 1947-03-01  <NA>
```

so my question is really simple --  I don't understand why the date1 works but date2 doesn't.

Comment: If instead of "why" you had asked for "how", then the answer would have been" `require(zoo); d1$date2 <- as.yearmon(d1$d2, format="%b/%Y")`

Comment: The `"yearmon"` class in the zoo package can handle year/months with no days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest answer is that a date is something which includes a day and if one is not specified, as.Date() gets confused. From the ?as.Date documentation:

> If the date string does not specify the date completely, the
>   returned answer may be system-specific.  The most common behaviour
>   is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one.
>   If it specifies a date incorrectly, reliable implementations will
>   give an error and the date is reported as ‘NA’.  Unfortunately
>   some common implementations (such as ‘glibc’) are unreliable and
>   guess at the intended meaning.

When you think about it, a term such as "Mar/1947" is not, strictly speaking, a date - it's just a combination of month and year.  A date is a specific day in March 1947 (or any other month + year) - since you don't specify one, you don't have a date.

Answer (score 9):

It is because `d2` in your `data.frame` is a malformed date.  It doesn't contain a day.  To get round this, consider using the following:

```
d1$date2 <- as.Date(x=paste("1/",d1$d2, sep=""), format="%d/%b/%Y")
> d1
           d       d2      date1      date2
1 1/Jan/1947 Jan/1947 1947-01-01 1947-01-01
2 1/Feb/1947 Feb/1947 1947-02-01 1947-02-01
3 1/Mar/1947 Mar/1947 1947-03-01 1947-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but %b doesn't seem to work when it's the leading field.

The following all fail (give NA):

```
> as.Date("Jan/1947", format="%b/%Y")
> as.Date("Jan 1947", format="%b %Y")
> as.Date("jan1947", format="%b%Y")
> as.Date("Jan1947", format="%b%Y")
```

whereas when you precede %b with %d, it works:

```
> as.Date("1Jan1947", format="%d%b%Y")
> as.Date("29-Jan-1947", format="%d-%b-%Y")
> as.Date("08/Aug/1947", format="%d/%b/%Y")
> as.Date("22 Dec 1947", format="%d %b %Y")
```

Seems like neilfws has the answer about incompleteness.
This would also explain why giving only the year gives:

```
> as.Date("1947", format="%Y")
[1] "1947-09-19"
```

Comment: Problem is not that %b is the leading field, but that a day is missing.

Answer (score -1):

As per the document,"Handling date-times in R" by Cole Beck, internally a date is saved as a single numeric value, which counts the number of days passed since a reference date, 1970-01-01. 
Example: 1970-01-31 will be saved internally as 30.

So, coming back to the problem, when a day (%d) is not mentioned in the given input date (i.e., an incomplete date), it cannot store the date internally, resulting in "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion"

Source: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/ColeBeck/datestimes.pdf