# Convert R character to date

Tags: r, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting year and month to a date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r)

I have the following string:

```
date <- "Feb 1964"
```

I am trying to convert this to a date, using the following code:

```
new.date <- as.Date(date, format="%b %Y")
```

**NA** is returned here. Can someone kindly explain how I can achieve this, and explain what I am doing wrong ..

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480499/unable-to-format-months-with-as-date

Comment: Thanks, issue has been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do what you want.

```
date <- "Feb 1964"
date <- "1 Feb 1964"
new.date <- as.Date(date, format="%d %b %Y")
new.date
```