# as.Date not working as expected

Tags: r, date, datestamp

This works as expected:

```
> as.Date("07/01/08","%m/%d/%y")
[1] "2008-07-01"
```

But not this:

```
> as.Date("07/08","%m/%y")
[1] NA
```

Bonus question, explain this:

```
> as.Date("08","%y")
[1] "2008-09-08"
```

**UPDATE**

OK, so I guess I can get something reasonable with this?

```
my.date = "07/08"
as.Date(paste0("01/",my.date),"%m/%d/%y")
```

Anything simpler? I've got a column of month/years I'd like to convert to Date objects:

```
my.dates = c("07/08","08/08","09/08","10/08")
as.Date(paste0("01/",my.dates),"%m/%d/%y")
```

Comment: Looks like your third example `as.Date("08","%y")` uses the current date and changes the year. It appears that such default behavior was not designed with your second example `as.Date("07/08","%m/%y")`.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480499/unable-to-format-months-with-as-date

Comment: See `?yearmon` from the `zoo` package to do what you want with month/year data.